# What are good solutions for associating an identifier with a message?

Tags: c#, string, message

Sometimes apps start off emitting human readable strings (such as log message for example) and then later we determine that going forward we want to process these strings programmatically, perhaps showing certain strings one way, or counting up other kinds of strings to show an occurrence count.

In order to do this, the code that processes those strings needs to have an idea what each strings "means", so it can be classified and dealt with accordingly...my question is how to best do this? Obviously you don't want your code doing string comparisons against the text of each message.. that's awkward and fragile.

Some solutions I've seen involve prefixing the string with a message identifier like M123, so your processing code can read this identifier and determine from that how to process the string. This seems less than desirable too because you have to keep track of the message identifiers that have already been used, etc.

Exmaple: you have an app that starts up a number of robots, issuing all sorts of commands to them to get them initialized, and to do the desired tasks. Initially the various parts of your app that interact with the robots issue textual messages to some output (perhaps a log), like this:

Robot 1 start initialization
Robot 1 waiting for SSH reply
Robot 2 start initialization
Robot 4 initialization complete
Robot 3 failed to reply within timeout
Robot 1 being shut down
...

After a while you realize that in addition to the textual scrolling log, you'd like to graphically show some sort of representation of each robot, perhaps a window with a check box for each important milestone that can happen in its lifetime. This would be a more useful, alternative UI.

For example, you'd like to show a checked box when a Robot has successfully started, and for when it has successfully completed its task and so on.

The question becomes, how should this new "view" interpret the current messages being emitted by your app so that it knows what they "mean" and can process them? For example, if the view wants to show an indicator for a Robot that has completed initialization, should it be doing a string comparison against the log messages looking for the text "Robot N initialization complete"? That seems fragile, as you might tweak the text of the log message some day.

One option might be to prefix the emission of each log message with a unique, non-changing message identifier such as "M24 Robot 1 has completed initialization". This, way, the new view just parses out the M24 and knows that stands for an "initialization complete".

Comment: This is pretty vague and abstract.  Can you show us a concrete example of what you're talking about?

Comment: [KeyValuePair](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5tbh8a42%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: Going out on a limb here...are you trying to associate a number (error code) with logged messages? With the goal of unique error codes but also static values that do not change between compilations?

Comment: Based on your updated question, I have some thoughts, but more than can fit into a comment while the question is on hold.

Answer (score 1):

in this case i see one simple class with with 2 props... one string and another identifier and i need to keep it in memory..." At runtime user see only string property but programmatically i'll access ad hidden property... To reconduct this class at simple string, you can override ToString methos...

for example

```
public class Message
{
    public void int MessageId {get; set;}
    public void string UserMessage {get; set;}

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return UserMessage;
    }
}
```

Comment: That's pretty close to what I was thinking. I can't think of a better way, but it feels less than ideal. I thought perhaps our industry had a better pattern for classifying string entities to make them more easily recognizable to code.